# NSKeyedArchiver duplication of encoding keys and iOS8 issues

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nskeyedarchiver

I have an obj-c app with autolayout (iPhone 4s through 6 plus compatible) that runs fine in iOS7 (devices and simulator), when I run it on iOS 8 and above it still runs fine but I get the following errors in the console.

```
*** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key 'UIScale'; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
*** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key 'UIImageOrientation'; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
*** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key 'UIHasPattern'; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
*** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key 'UIRenderingMode'; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
```

The problem is that I don't use any of those keys nor NSKeyedArchiver in my code, so I can't really understand where this is originated and what exactly means as the app is running just fine.

I'm using several frameworks and pods, so I thought this could be caused buy on of them, and I think it could be iAD (I'm using native framework with the easy setup Apple gave in the WWDC videos), other frameworks/pods loading at the time of the console error are MKNetworkKit and Google Analytics.

Did anybody experience any of those?
Or do you have any leads to further investigation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.
The problem was related to the fact that in the appDelegate I was using an image for the navigationBar.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBkg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1]}];
```

I commented these lines and changed the navigationBar via Interface Builder instead. I'm not getting those errors anymore.